# For every single birth day, it types "Thirtyfirst" and says "DateName" is unused?

Tags: java, javascript, string

```
String MonthName = "" ; 

String DateName = "" ;

String sign = "" ;

String horoscope = "" ;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter your month of birth as an integer: ");

int month= scan.nextInt();

System.out.println(" ");

System.out.println("Please enter your date of birth as an integer: ");

int date = scan.nextInt();

System.out.println(" ");


if (month == 1) {

    MonthName = "January";

} else if (month == 2) {

    MonthName = "February";

} else if (month == 3) {

    MonthName = "March";

} else if (month == 4) {

    MonthName = "April";

} else if (month == 5) {

    MonthName = "May" ;

} else if (month == 6) {

    MonthName = "June" ;

} else if (month == 7) {

    MonthName = "July" ;

} else if (month == 8) {

    MonthName = "August" ;

} else if (month == 9) {

    MonthName = "September" ;

} else if (month == 10) {

    MonthName = "October" ;

} else if (month == 11) {

    MonthName = "November" ;

} else if (month == 12) {

    MonthName = "December" ;
}


if (date == 1) {

    DateName = "first";

} else if (date == 2) {

    DateName = "second" ;

} else if (date == 3) {

    DateName = "third" ;

} else if (date == 4) {

    DateName = "fourth" ;

} else if (date == 5) {

    DateName = "fifth" ;

} else if (date == 6) {

    DateName = "sixth" ;

} else if (date == 7) {

    DateName = "seventh" ;

} else if (date == 8) {

    DateName = "eighth" ;

}  else if (date == 9) {

    DateName = "nineth" ;

}  else if (date == 10) {

    DateName = "tenth";

} else  if (date == 11) {

    DateName = "eleventh";

} else if (date == 12) {

    DateName = "twelfth";

} else  if (date == 13) {

    DateName = "thirteenth";

} else if (date == 14) {

    DateName = "fourteenth";

} else if (date == 15) {

    DateName = "fifteenth" ;

} else if (date == 16) {

    DateName = "sixteenth" ;

} else if (date == 17) {

    DateName = "seventeenth" ;

} else if (date == 18) {

    DateName = "eighteenth" ;

} else if (date == 19) {

    DateName = "nineteenth";

} else if (date == 20) {

    DateName = "twentieth";

} else if (date == 21) {

    DateName = "twentyfirst";

} else if (date == 22) {

    DateName = "twentysecond";

} else if (date == 23) {

    DateName = "twenty-third";

} else if (date == 24) {

    DateName = "twenty-fourth";

} else if (date == 25) {

    DateName = "twentyfifth";

} else if (date == 26) {

    DateName = "twentysixth";

} else if (date == 27) {

    DateName = "twentyseventh";

} else if (date == 28) {

    DateName = "twentyeight";

} else if (date == 29) {

    DateName = "twentynineth";

} else if (date == 30) {

    DateName = "thirtieth";

} else if (date == 31) ;

   DateName = "thirtyfirst" ;


if((month == 1) && (date <= 20) || (month == 12) && (date >= 22)) {

sign = "Capricorn";

} else if((month == 1) || (month == 2) && (date <= 19)) {

sign = "Aquarius";

} else if((month == 2) || (month == 3) && (date <= 20)) {

sign = "Pisces";

} else if((month == 3) || (month == 4) && (date <= 19)) {

sign = "Aries";

} else if((month == 4) || (month == 5) && (date <= 21)) {

sign = "Taurus";

} else if((month == 5) || (month == 6) && (date <= 21)) {

sign = "Gemini";

} else if((month == 6) || (month == 7) && (date <= 23)) {

sign = "Cancer";

} else if((month == 7) || (month == 8) && (date <= 23)) {

sign = "Leo";

} else if((month == 8) || (month == 9) && (date <= 23)) {

sign = "Virgo";

} else if((month == 9) || (month == 10) && (date <= 23)) {

sign = "Libra";

} else if((month == 10) || (month == 11) && (date <= 22)) {

sign = "Scorpio";

} else if(month == 12) {

sign = "Sagittarius";

}


if (sign.equals("Aries")) {

   horoscope= " You are the pioneer type and think most people are quick-tempered, impatient, and irritating.";

} else if (sign.equals("Leo")) {

    horoscope = "You consider yourself a born leader while others think you're the biggest bully out there. ";

} else if (sign.equals("Sagittarius")) {

    horoscope = "It's your time to be successful around the 19th!";

} else if (sign.equals("Taurus")) {

    horoscope = " Most people think you are stubborn and bullheaded. You are actually nothing but a communist.";

} else if (sign.equals("Virgo")) {

    horoscope = "You are logical, cold and unemotional, and hate disorder to an extreme level, like seriously.";

} else if (sign.equals("Capricorn")) {

    horoscope = "You are conservative and are afraid of taking risks, so you should just become a monk. ";

} else if (sign.equals("Gemini")) {

    horoscope = "You are a quick and intelligent thinkery Also, you are inclined to expect way too much for too little.";

} else if (sign.equals("Libra")) {

    horoscope = "You are the artistic type and have a difficult time with reality. Ouch, life must be hard for you."; 

} else if (sign.equals("Aquarius")) {

    horoscope = "You  are inclined to be progressive because you lie a great deal even though you make many mistakes."; 

} else if (sign.equals("Cancer")) {

    horoscope = "You are sympathetic and understanding to other peoples problems, yet you need to stop putting things off. ";

} else if (sign.equals("Scorpio")) {

    horoscope = "You are shrewd in business and cannot be trusted. You shall achieve the pinnacle of success because of your total lack of ethics";

} else if (sign.equals("Pisces")) {

    horoscope = "You have a vivid imagination and often think you are being followed by the FBI or CIA. Like, you need to wake up. ";

}


System.out.println("Your birthday is: " + MonthName + " " + DateName);

System.out.println(" ");

System.out.println("Your horoscope sign is: " + sign);

System.out.println(" ");

System.out.println("Horoscope: "+ horoscope);
System.out.println(" ");

    }

}
```

Comment: Whoa... Please include just the code that's relevant to your question, and check out the code formatting guidelines in the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a semicolon where one should not be. These lines of your code

```
} else if (date == 31) ;

DateName = "thirtyfirst" ;
```

are unconditionally setting `DateName` to `"thirtyfirst"` regardless of what happens in the preceding chain of `if/else` tests. Replace the above with:

```
} else if (date == 31) {
    DateName = "thirtyfirst" ;
}
```

As an aside: you should learn to use arrays for this. It will vastly simplify your code.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but as I can't yet comment...

You'll probably also be better off using a Calendar (I usually use GregorianCalendar myself) and applying formatting - that way you'll be able to neaten your code. Also, if you do decide to display the date of birth differently in the future, it'll be less rework.

It seems like you're a bit new to programming, so you may also find "case statements" useful. You'll probably also be better able to spot errors/missing blocks, like in your posted example code here. (The other two answers have already provided a solution, so I won't re-iterate.)